# SVG properties are ignored in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, responsive-design, inline-svg

I am currently working on responsive SVG. On Chrome everything looks good and works. But on Firefox, my cx cy cr properties in CSS aren't applied.

On Chrome CSS overrides inline SVG as it should but on Firefox it doesn't work.

[Properties on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si4KK.png)

[HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m8tQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Firefox now supports geometric properties.

But make sure you include units with your values.

---

The ability to style geometric properties, sauch as `cx`, `cy` and `r`, is a new feature of the upcoming SVG 2 standard.

Chrome has implemented that part of SVG2, but Firefox hasn't yet.

If you need to support all browsers, you will need to set those attributes a different way.

Comment: Is there a way that you would recommend?

Comment: You could have different versions (i.e. sizes)  of the circles in the SVG. Then show or hide them using something like `.biggerCircle { visibility: visible; }`.  Otherwise you would need to alter those attributes with Javascript.

Comment: @RobertLongson Done